# how to assign cordova GoogleMap to java script map PlacesService method in Ionic 4?

Tags: google-maps, cordova-plugins, ionic4, google-places

i'm using GoogleMap cordova plugin in ionic 4, it's working right.
but when i try to install the Google Maps functionality to work better in typeScript i cant pass map object to google.map.place.placesService();

```
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapOptions} from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';

declare var google: any;
....
....
const options: GoogleMapOptions = {
  controls: {
    compass: true,
    myLocationButton: true,
    myLocation: true,   //  (blue dot)
    indoorPicker: true,
    zoom: true,          //  android only
    mapToolbar: true     //  android only
  },
  gestures: {
    scroll: true,
    tilt: true,
    zoom: true,
    rotate: true
  },
  camera: {
    target: {
      lat: this.latLng.lat,
      lng: this.latLng.lng
    },
    zoom: 9
  },
  styles: [], //  https:// developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference
  preferences: {
    zoom: {
      minZoom: 1,
      maxZoom: 23
    },
    padding: {
      left: 10,
      top: 10,
      bottom: 10,
      right: 10
    },
    building: true
  }
};
this.map = GoogleMaps.create("gmap_Canvas", options);
```

when i use placesService like this:

```
this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
```

it's working. but when i installed google map for typescript and remove declaration of => var google

```
npm install @types/google-maps --save
```

i got this error:

```
Argument of type 'GoogleMap' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLDivElement | Map<Element>'.
```

placesServices not accepted this.map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I droped PlacesService and then pass the full Address from autoComplete to Google.geoCode

after map is loaded:

```
async loadMap(){
    ...
    this.autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
}

searchPlace() {
    let config = {
        types: ['geocode'],
        input: this.query
    }

    this.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(config, (predictions, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK && predictions) {

          this.places = [];

          predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
              this.places.push(prediction);
          });
      }
    });
```

and finaly i got geocode from this method:

```
getCoder(place: any) {

    this.places = [];

    const options: GeocoderRequest = {
      address: place.description
    };

    // Address -> latitude,longitude
    Geocoder.geocode(options).then((results: GeocoderResult[]) => {
      console.log(results);
      this.map.setCameraTarget(results[0].position);
    });
```

}

from html page:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="query" (ionInput)="searchPlace()"></ion-searchbar>
```

with PlaceService we had Place_id but with geocode i think(i'm not sure) we must get address again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial may this can help you

`https://medium.com/ramsatt/integrate-google-maps-on-ionic-4-beta-application-37497dbc12e3`

Comment: thank you, it doesn't use GoogleMap from cordova, and from their doc i saw it's not supported for placesService